# Export layer with hue and saturation mask to PNG with javascript

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

i'm working on the script that will export all layers in PNG but I have some problem with layer that has Hue & saturation or layer mask. It consider two different layers and export 2 images. Is there anyway to export layer to image with layer mask on it ?
Thanks

Comment: What code have you written so far? Is it JavaScript, VB or AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

What you will have to so is **destructive** In that exporting the layers to pngs you will alter the original .PSD.

What I recommend you do in this case it to flatten the layer with the hue & saturation mask on it. This can be done by applying the mask or more easily adding a new blank layer above the hue & saturation and merge down. That way you'll only get one image for that layer.

Do **NOT** save over your original .psd or you'll lose the h&s layer

```
loop over all image layers
  is it an image layer? (export as normal)
  is it a hue & saturation layer? - Add new layer above, merge it down
  export current layer as .png
```